# Displaying message if no photo present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the code:

```
<%= image_tag site.photo.url(:small) if site.photo.file? %>
```

to tell my app to display nothing if there is no photo associated with a particular post (site in this case). Is there a way to render a message along w/ this. For instance "no image with the post". I tried simply doing

```
<%= if site.photo.file? %>
  <p> no image with this site </p>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. New to ruby and rails if you can't tell.

Comment: I'm not familiar with rails but wouldn't if site.photo.file? return true if there was a photo?  Wouldn't you want the opposite of that?

Comment: Yea you are correct which I think is addressed through the .empty? or .blank? addition to the end but I think there is a way to do it in the first set of code perhaps using and 'else' statement but not sure of the syntax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag(site.photo.url(:small)) rescue "<p>No image</p>" %>
```

Comment: I thought you could only use rescue in conjunction with Begin, how does this work?

Comment: It's an "inline rescue". If the left side of the expression triggers an error, it can be recovered from immediately with the statement on the right. E.g., in the example above, if `site` does not have a `photo`, `site.photo.url` is going to complain "undefined method `url' for `nil'". Rather than doing testing for this, just rescue and render "Whoa! No photo, man."

Answer (score 4):

Your code will output `no image with this site` when there is a photo. Use this instead:

```
<% unless site.photo.file? %>
  <p> no image with this site </p>
<% end %>
```

or even better:

```
<% if site.photo.file? %>
  <%= image_tag site.photo.url(:small) %>
<% else %>
  <p> no image with this site </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<%= ... %>` outputs to the Document. Write display logic as (e.g.,) `<% unless site.photo.file? %> ...` (No `=` character)

Answer (score 2):

A real simple way would be to create a small little helper:

```
def show_photo_if_exists(photo)
  photo.file? ? image_tag photo.url(:small) : "No image with this site"
end
```

Then in your view call:

```
<%= show_photo_if_exists(site.photo) %>
```

Comment: if `site.photo` is nil, you're passing nil to the `show_photo_if_exists` method. The first statement of that method becomes `nil.file?` of which will return an `undefined method\`file?' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: It looks to me like he's using Paperclip, in which case as long as the Site model `has_attached_file :photo` then `site.photo` will never be nil, not even if it has no attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but missing a bit of logic you want to display it only if site.photo.file? returns false, so you would need to use this in your view:

```
<%= if !site.photo.file? %>
  <p> no image with this site </p>
<% end %>
```

(note the bang! in front of site.photo.file? which will invert the logic.)

Comment: This is not idiomatic ruby. Ruby has a "if not" keyword `unless`. `<% unless site.photo.file? %> ...` **Note:**, you want `<% ...`, not `<%= ...`.